An event listener using named function with arguments of element id's and then remove event listener upon completion of task
I was making a tic tac toe using JS . It came out fine but even after a player wins it still let us mark down the empty boxes. So i tried to enclose the main program into a named function and passed the id's of the boxes as arguments to it using Event Listener, but it didn't work. Does anybody know why is it not working ? It's coming out like this without clicking on any of the boxes.
I tried doing this :-
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".board-boxes");
for(let box of boxes){
    box.addEventListener('click', tic_tac_toe(box))
}

function tic_tac_toe(box){
    const box_id = box.getAttribute('id');
        // console.log(box_id,typeof box_id);

        if(box.innerHTML == ""){
        box.innerHTML = marker_update();
        }
        win_check(box);
}

Here the boxes are getting filled with their id's without being clicked on:-
enter image description here
The only thing i could do was to fill up all the empty boxes with comments
for(let box of boxes){
         box.innerHTML = `<!-- Filled Up-->`
                  }

Is there any way where i can remove the event listener from the boxes upon a player winning?

box.addEventListener('click', function() {tic_tac_toe(box);})
